# "TypeError: compute_integral() got multiple values for argument 'limits'" using register_analytic_integral

Tags: python, zfit

I defined my own ZFit pdf using something like:

```
class AngularPDFWithAcceptance(zfit.pdf.BasePDF):
    def __init__(self, ctl_name, ctk_name, phi_name, params, name):
        from math import pi
        ctl = zfit.Space(ctl_name, limits=(-1.0, 1.0))
        ctk = zfit.Space(ctk_name, limits=(-1.0, 1.0))
        phi = zfit.Space(phi_name, limits=(-pi, pi))
        obs = ctl*ctk*phi
        super().__init__(obs=obs, params=params, name=name)
        integral_full_limits = zfit.Space(axes=self.axes, limits = self.space.limits)
        self.register_analytic_integral( self.compute_integral_full_limits, integral_full_limits )
    ...
     def compute_integral_full_limits(limits, params, model):
        # this is the integral over 8pi
        ...
        return normalization
```

When creating the PDF I get an error

```
...
  File "/data/bfys/wouterh/miniconda3/envs/bd2ksteeEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zfit/core/integration.py", line 606, in __call__
    return self.integrate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/bfys/wouterh/miniconda3/envs/bd2ksteeEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zfit/core/space.py", line 2777, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: compute_integral() got multiple values for argument 'limits'
```

Can anybody tell what I do wrong ? Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I solved this by moving the definition of the ```compute_integral_full_limits``` function out of the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

The issue here arises since the integral registration is done in the init for the instance, but it is actually a class method and should be registered with the class, not on an instance (*details on the technicality of the error below*).

### Solution

So the example should look like:

```
class AngularPDFWithAcceptance(zfit.pdf.BasePDF):
    def __init__(self, ctl_name, ctk_name, phi_name, params, name):
        from math import pi
        ctl = zfit.Space(ctl_name, limits=(-1.0, 1.0))
        ctk = zfit.Space(ctk_name, limits=(-1.0, 1.0))
        phi = zfit.Space(phi_name, limits=(-pi, pi))
        obs = ctl*ctk*phi
        super().__init__(obs=obs, params=params, name=name)
    ...
 def compute_integral_full_limits(limits, params, model):
    # this is the integral over 8pi
    ...
    return normalization

# the following code is duplicated, one could refactor it, i.e. into a class method/attribute
from math import pi
ctl = zfit.Space(ctl_name, limits=(-1.0, 1.0))
ctk = zfit.Space(ctk_name, limits=(-1.0, 1.0))
phi = zfit.Space(phi_name, limits=(-pi, pi))
obs = ctl*ctk*phi
integral_full_limits = zfit.Space(axes=self.axes, limits = self.space.limits)  AngularPDFWithAcceptance.register_analytic_integral(compute_integral_full_limits, integral_full_limits)
```

### Explanation

The problem is that `compute_integral_full_limits` is an (instance) method. As such, it will take as the first (hidden) argument `self` automatically. However, since the registration function is a classmethod, it somehow messes up somewhere the signature, i.e. does not provide the self automatically as the first argument. Therefore, most likely, limits are given as the first *as well as* the second argument somehow